# Parse Hibernate Log messages

Tags: sql, hibernate

When I open hibernate loggers I get the statements with bind variables and then the list of variables and their values. For example

```
   DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into EMPLOY (NAME, LAST_NAME, CITY) values (?,?,?) 
   DEBUG org.hibernate.type.TimestampType - binding 'John' to parameter: 1 
   DEBUG org.hibernate.type.IntegerType - binding 'Doe' to parameter: 2 
   DEBUG org.hibernate.type.StringType - binding 'NY' to parameter: 3
```

I want to parse the log to an sql scripts and get a list of combined commands such as

```
   insert into EMPLOY (NAME, LAST_NAME, CITY) values ('John','Doe','NY')
```

Anyone knows of a parser that does that?